# Synaptic: How to completely remove dependant packages by default?

Tags: debian, package-management, dependencies, synaptic, uninstall

I want to sort out some preinstalled programs, but when a package depends on the package I want to remove, it only gets marked for removal, not complete removal, so I have to mark all of them for complete removal manually. Is there a way to automate it, maybe a setting I missed?

Answer (score 0):

Open the Preferences (from the Settings menu), and select “Completely” in the “Removal of packages” drop-down:

[image: Synaptic preferences dialog]

This will cause packages which are automatically selected for removal to be selected for complete removal.

Comment: It's already set to "completely".